# Modules not found that are required in module-info.java

Tags: java, gradle, java-11, java-module, module-info

All the required modules I've declared in `module-info.java` are not being found when I run gradle:

```
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:10: error: module not found: com.jfoenix
        requires com.jfoenix;
                    ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:11: error: module not found: google.api.client
        requires google.api.client;
                           ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:12: error: module not found: google.api.services.gmail.v1.rev83
        requires google.api.services.gmail.v1.rev83;
                                             ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:13: error: module not found: google.http.client
        requires google.http.client;
                            ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:14: error: module not found: google.http.client.jackson2
        requires google.http.client.jackson2;
                                   ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:15: error: module not found: google.oauth.client
        requires google.oauth.client;
                             ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:16: error: module not found: google.oauth.client.java6
        requires google.oauth.client.java6;
                                    ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:17: error: module not found: google.oauth.client.jetty
        requires google.oauth.client.jetty;
                                    ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:18: error: module not found: java.xml.bind
        requires java.xml.bind;
                         ^
/Users/Joseph/eclipse-workspace/CheckMyDigitalFootprint/src/main/java/module-info.java:23: error: module not found: org.json
        requires org.json;
```

module-info.java:

```
module footprint {

    requires com.jfoenix;
    requires google.api.client;
    requires google.api.services.gmail.v1.rev83;
    requires google.http.client;
    requires google.http.client.jackson2;
    requires google.oauth.client;
    requires google.oauth.client.java6;
    requires google.oauth.client.jetty;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    requires transitive javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires org.json;
    requires java.prefs;

    opens checkmydigitalfootprint to javafx.fxml;


    exports checkmydigitalfootprint.util;
    exports checkmydigitalfootprint;
    exports checkmydigitalfootprint.model;
    exports checkmydigitalfootprint.view;
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Is the issue when you run with Gradle? What command are you executing and which version of Gradle? Do update the question with your `build.gradle` as well.

Comment: yes when i run gradle build or run. I'm using gradle 5.0

Comment: Just to start off, you can follow https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules . In general, you haven't placed those modules form your dependencies on the modulepath while building with Java11.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to ensure to [modify the `compileJava` task](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compilejava_code_task_to_produce_a_module) as :

```
compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In recent Gradle versions (since 6.4 says the Internet; I tested on 6.5), this can be stated more concisely:

```
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}
```

Again, see also: https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/